# How do i evaluate a nested summation with fraction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

i have to evaluate this expression, but im not sure how to begin.

$$\sum^{4}_{i=1}\sum^{5-i}_{j=2} \frac{(j+1)^2}{(2i-1)}$$

Comment: Sum over $j$ and hope the numerator and denominator play nice for the final summation. The first is a summation of a quadratic so that has a standard form with an appropiate shift of index.

Comment: If you just need an answer, you can manually step through it.  It's not too many steps.

Answer (score 2):

The sum has six terms.

- When $i=1$, $j$ can be $2,3,$ or $4$.  (Why?)
- When $i=2$, $j$ can be $2$ or $3$.
- When $i=3$, $j$ can be $2$.
- When $i=4$, the upper limit is less than the lower limit, so there are no terms for this value of $i.$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

The series
\begin{align}
\sum^{4}_{i=1}\sum^{5-i}_{j=2} \frac{(j+1)^2}{(2i-1)}
\end{align}
can be seen to be 
\begin{align}
S &= \sum^{4}_{i=1} \frac{1}{2i-1} \, \left(\sum^{5-i}_{j=2} (j+1)^2\right) \\
&= \left(\sum^{4}_{j=2} (j+1)^2\right) + \frac{1}{3} \, \left(\sum^{3}_{j=2} (j+1)^2\right) + \frac{1}{5} \, \left(\sum^{2}_{j=2} (j+1)^2\right) + \frac{1}{7} \, \left(\sum^{1}_{j=2} (j+1)^2\right).
\end{align}
The last term is zero because the summation is ill-defined. This leaves
\begin{align}
S &= (3^{2} + 4^{2} + 5^{2}) + \frac{3^{2} + 4^{2}}{3} + \frac{3^{2}}{5} = \frac{902}{15}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
using
$\sum_{j=1}^m j^2 = \frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)
&=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{n+1-i}_{j=2} \frac{(j+1)^2}{(2i-1)}\\
&=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac1{2i-1}\sum^{n+1-i}_{j=2} (j+1)^2\\
&=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac1{2i-1}\sum^{n+2-i}_{j=3} j^2\\
&=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac1{2i-1}\sum^{n+2-i}_{j=3} j^2\\
&=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac1{2i-1}\left(\sum^{n+2-i}_{j=1} j^2 - (1^2+2^2)\right)\\
&=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac1{2i-1}\left(\frac{(n+2-i)(n+3-i)(2n+5-2i)}{6} - 5\right)\\
&=\frac1{6}\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{(n+2-i)(n+3-i)(2n+5-2i)}{2i-1} - 5\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac1{2i-1}\\
\end{array}
$

I will now try to write
that numerator
as a function of $2i-1$
to simplify the fraction
as much as possible.

$\begin{array}\\
(n+2-i)(n+3-i)(2n+5-2i)
&=\frac14(2n+4-2i)(2n+6-2i)(2n+5-2i)\\
&=-\frac14(2i-4-2n)(2i-6-2n)(2i-5-2n)\\
&=-\frac14(k-3-2n)(k-5-2n)(k-4-2n)
\quad(k = 2i-1)\\
&=-\frac14(k-(u-1))(k-u)(k-(u+1))
\quad(u=2n+4)\\
&=-\frac14((k-u)-1))(k-u)((k-u)+1))\\
&=-\frac14((k-u)^3-(k-u))\\
&=-\frac14(k^3-3k^2u+3ku^2-u^3-(k-u))\\
&=-\frac14(k^3-3k^2u+k(3u^2-1)-u^3+u)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
remembering that
$k = 2i-1$ and
$u = 2n+4$,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{(n+2-i)(n+3-i)(2n+5-2i)}{2i-1}
&=-\frac14\frac{k^3-3k^2u+k(3u^2-1)-u^3+u}{k}\\
&=-\frac14(k^2-3ku+3u^2-1+\frac{-u^3+u}{k})\\
&=-\frac14((2i-1)^2-3u(2i-1)+3u^2-1+\frac{-u^3+u}{2i-1})\\
\end{array}
$

At this point,
everything in
the sum of this formula
can be done explicitly
as a polynomial in $n$,
except for the
sum of
$\frac1{2i-1}$.

So I'll leave it at this.